# How to work with double pointers and printf in int safecpy(char **t, char *s)?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, copy

I am trying to implement the Function "int safecpy(char **t, char *s)" and it is for copying an array into another. I actually have some trouble with the usage of the doublepointers. The function returns 1 for succsess and 0 for error. 
I actually want to printf the copied array but I always gets stuck or the array is not even shown in the end.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int safecpy(char **t, char *s);

int main (void)
{
char *t, *v, i;
char s[] = "abcd";
if (safecpy(&t, &s) == NULL)
{
    printf("No memory.");
    return 1;
}
printf("The copied Array:");
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    printf("%i", t[i]);
}
free(t);
return 0;

}

int safecpy(char **t, char *s)
{
int i;
*t = malloc(strlen(s+1)*sizeof(char));
if (*t == NULL)
{
    return NULL;
}
for(i = 0; i < (strlen(s)+1); i++)
{
    *t[i] = s[i];
    printf("i = %i\n", i);
}
return 1;
}
```

I tried to change `*t[i] = s[i];` to `t[i] = s[i];`. Then the for runned through the whole process but I was still not able to print `t` now.

When I run with `*t[i]` it gets stuck after `i = i` and I don't get the reason. Then I am also not sure how the whole `printf` and the usage of the double pointers is correct here or not.

Comment: `malloc(strlen(s+1)*sizeof(char))` should be `malloc(strlen(s)+1)` and `*t[i]` should be `(*t)[i]`

Comment: Your compiler should be shouting warnings at you. `&s` is *not* of type `char *`. However, `&s[0]` (which is what plain `s` decays to) is.

Comment: ah nice! :) thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by changing

```
 *t = malloc(strlen(s+1)*sizeof(char));
```

to

```
*t = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
```

as

- `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1 in C. No point using that as a multiplier.
- `strlen(s+1)` actually does exactly opposite of what you think. You need to add 1 to the string length (the returned value of `strlen()`), not start counting one past the initial element.

That said, as per the [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), the array subscript binds prior to the pointer dereference operator, so you need to enforce the binding expilitly using parenthesis, as you want the statement to be parsed as

```
(*t)[i] = s[i]; // you want to index over the memory pointed to by (*t)
```

not as

```
*(t[i]) = s[i]; // default parsing without forced precedence.
```

**Some other points:**

- You need to change the call `if (safecpy(&t, &s) == NULL)` to `if (safecpy(&t, s) == 0)`, because, the second argument of `safecpy()` takes a `char *`, and an array name, when passed as a function argument, decays to pointer to the emenelnt type, in this case, `char *`. `&array` would be of type `char (*)[n]`, which is not the same as `char *`. Also, as the function retunrs an `int`, you need to check it against an `int` value.
- Change `return NULL;` to `return 0;` in the `safecpy()` function, it returns an `int`, not a pointer.
- In `main()`, defining `i` as `char` does you no good, change it to an `int`.
- Variable `v` is unused, you can get rid of that.
- In your `main()`, the snippet

  ```
  printf("The copied Array:");
  for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
      printf("%i", t[i]);
  }
  ```

  has to be changed to

  ```
  printf("The copied Array:");
  for(i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)  //don't use magic numbers
  {
      printf("%c", t[i]);         // you want to see 'char' values, not `int` values
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, did you mean

```
*t = malloc(strlen(s+1) * sizeof(char));
```

or

```
*t = malloc((strlen(s) + 1) * sizeof(char);
```

?

As `strlen(s+1)` is equal to `strlen(s) - 1`.

Regarding your question, try `(*t)[1]`, so you dereference `char**` to `char*`, and then dereference to `char` using the member access operator `[]`.

Comment: `return NULL` =》 `return 0`

Comment: Compile source with `-Wall` and always solve the shown warnings, as the C language let's you do operations which make sense for the compiler, but which are not right from a programming standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

```
int safecpy(char **t, char *s)
```

It seems to be wrong

```
char *t, *v, i;
char s[] = "abcd";
if (safecpy(&t, &s) == NULL)
```

Here `t` and `s` are pointers to char `(char *)` so, when you are passing a pointer to pointer the result type is `char **`. You need to change function header

```
int safecpy(char **t, char *s)
```

to

```
int safecpy(char **t, char **s)
```

Or another way is to change `&s` to `s` in function call:

```
if (safecpy(&t, &s) == NULL)
```

I think you may want to change rather `&s` to `s` as you use `s` as input array in safecpy function

Comment: Ah I see makes sense! the compiler gave some warnings with -Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic but the program was still functioning

Comment: It's recomended to use -Wall flag and treat every warning as an error, because many strange things could happen. Unfortunately some compilers have some warnings turned off, this is why it's recomended to use -Wall. I remember some issue, when it was possible to call function with less parameter than it is defined, I stuck in this because I didn't put -Wall